# Haskell readFile illegal Char

Tags: file, haskell, io, locale

I need to read a File containing chars like 'ç' ou 'á'...
The Problem is that when I try to readFile a txt file, GHC returns: illegal byte sequence.
Is there a way around this?

```
main = do putStr "Insert file path\n"
          a <- getLine
          x <- readFile a
          print x

Main> main
Main> Insert file path
Main> /Users/$HOME/Desktop/File.txt
Main> (illegal byte sequence)
```

Thanks

Comment: GHC version, encoding of the file, and your system locale?  Unicode handling in the IO subsystem changed around GHC 6.12.1.

Answer (score 9):

[`Data.ByteString.readFile`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/bytestring-0.9.1.8/Data-ByteString.html#v:readFile) reads the file as a raw stream of bytes, whereas [`System.IO.readFile`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/System-IO.html#v:readFile) uses [`localeEncoding`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/System-IO.html#v:localeEncoding) to decode characters and will throw exceptions if the contents of the file cannot be decoded with your current locale.

If you want to continue to use [`String`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/Prelude.html#t:String) instead of [`ByteString`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/bytestring-0.9.1.8/Data-ByteString.html#t:ByteString)+decode, and you know the encoding of the file, you can specify it with

```
do handle <- openFile a ReadMode
   hSetEncoding handle latin1  -- or whatever applies
   x <- hGetContents handle
```